# How to pass arguments to a program from a web page?

Tags: linux, web-services, web, interface, scripting

I'll be the first to admit that my programming experience and skill in web services is practically non-existent. I usually program things that run completely isolated or locally, with either C or assembly. I'm proficient enough to get a website going, with some basic authentication and directory read access on the system. That's about it.

I'm trying to do a project that's well outside of my comfort zone and get some experience in controlling stuff remotely/via web. Using a Raspberry Pi running Debian, I'm running a program on it in C that takes in information such as video and UART data, does some crunching and triggers some outputs and writes events to a file/folder. This component is fairly straightforward to get running automatically. Getting a webserver up so a remote user can look at the files and pictures the driver program creates is also extremely easy.

The problem for me comes in trying to make a GUI on a webpage that can be used to manually control these outputs. I'm going to need some scripting to handle the button presses on the web page, clearly, but is there a scripting language in particular that stands out for using kernel objects/system calls so I can actually talk to that process? I figure the best way is to use message queues, but I don't know if Python or PHP (or another scripting language) are capable of doing this, and if there are any that are better at this than others. What is the preferred way of doing this?

I know it's possible since we've all seen those kitten-cams with the flash container where you can move the camera or trigger things. I just have no idea where to start.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Learning more about FastCGI or CGI could be useful. Also there are libraries in C providing HTTP service ...

Comment: Wow, I never even realized these libraries existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java can call native commands via JNI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) from within a JVM. So if you already have C code that can handle the controls, it's just a matter of getting Java code to call them.

As for the scripts to handle button presses, there are several options. One way is to do it asynchronously via AJAX (which requires some JavaScript knowledge) or the other is by doing the traditional page refresh on each press. Sorry to be a bit vague on the answer, but this requires a lengthy explanation of how the whole JSP (Java Server Pages)/Servlets eco system works.

Here's a good place to start:

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

---